# NullReferenceException when comparing null return value

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I came across this problem but have been unable to figure out what is causing it and have been unable to replicate it, despite my attempts here https://dotnetfiddle.net/xDVa2a. My classes are structured like so:

```
public abstract class ProductNode
{
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory : ProductNode { }

public class TreeNode<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly T _value;

    public T Value() {
        return _value;
    }

    public TreeNode(T value) {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

In my code I create a TreeNode of type ProductNode with the constructor argument as null and use LINQ to filter an IQueryable to compare the ProductNode against the value in the TreeNode.

```
IQueryable<ProductNode> allProductNodes = _context.ProductNodes;
TreeNode<ProductNode> treeNode = new TreeNode<ProductNode>(null);
List<ProductNode> productNodes = allProductNodes
    .Where(node => node.ParentCategory == treeNode.Value()).ToList(); // NullReferenceException
```

This throws a NullReferenceException, however if I tweak my query to compare against null it works.

```
List<ProductNode> productNodes = allProductNodes
    .Where(node => node.ParentCategory == null).ToList(); // Works

List<ProductNode> productNodes = allProductNodes
    .Where(node => node.ParentCategory == (treeNode.Value() ?? null)).ToList(); // Alternative, working solution
```

What is causing the compiler to throw the exception?

Comment: Does anything in there happen to overload the == operator? That's about the only thing I can imagine going wrong here...

Comment: Your `TreeNode<T>` class doesn't even compile. Please show real code that we can see your issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity My question was edited but now I have changed it back to how it was.

Comment: @drmathias My bad, didn't realize the second function was `_value = value;`. The expression body wasn't the issue, so that didn't need to be changed. `public TreeNode(T value) => _value = value;` would work.

Comment: Also, is this really a duplicate? This is more like the inverse, asking "Why isn't there a null reference exception?" not "I have one, how can I fix this?"

Comment: Sidenote, why is `Value()` not a property? It should either be named `GetValue()` or be replaced with `Value => _value;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using [the "??" operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) which returns `treeNode.Value()` if not null, and the right hand side if null.

So you are returning null in both cases, basically `null.ToList()` is your end result and where your Null Ref comes from.

Comment: That is the working solution that I am using, though your answer highlights my confusion. If I simply compare node.ParentCategory with treeNode.Value(), which should be null, it throws a NullReferenceException. When I use the ?? operator it does not throw the exception, because for some reason explicitly using the keyword is fine.

Comment: @drmathias When you compare node.ParentCategory with treeNode.Value() which should be null, are you still dereferencing it with .List() ?

Comment: OP is using `.ToList()` in all cases. The argument is that `.Where(node => node.ParentCategory == treeNode.Value()).ToList();` this causes `NullReferenceException`, but replacing `treeNode.Value()` with `null` does not, and replacing it with `(treeNode.Value() ?? null)` does not throw either. Besides, `IQueryable<T>.Where` should not return `null`, it will either return an `IEnumerable<T>` (perhaps empty), or throw `ArgumentNullException` because a parameter is `null` (the epxpresion or the source collection) or throw whatever inside throws. Thus, it will never reduce to `null.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `??` has no point if you're going to return `null` if it is `null`. What you probably want to do instead is this:

```
treeNode.Value()?.ToList();
```

That will make it so that, if `treeNode.Value()` is not null, it will call `.ToList()` on it. If it is `null`, however, `.ToList()` won't be called and that should get rid of that error.

Comment: That's the thing, `?? null` should have no point, but it is preventing the compiler from throwing the exception. I'm calling `ToList()` on the `Where()` clause in all cases, not on `treeNode.Value()`and as @Theraot pointed out `.Where()` should never return `null` or throw `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
List<ProductNode> productNodes = allProductNodes.ToList()
.Where(node => node.ParentCategory == (treeNode.Value() ?? null));
```

I am afraid calling a function (in this case `treeNode.Value()`) on `IQueryable` may result unusual behavior.